# Is the error 'name 'Scene' is not defined' in Maning a generic output, or does it have a concrete meaning, and how to fix it?

Tags: python, manim

Running on Windows VSC the following code from the [Manim examples](https://3b1b.github.io/manim/getting_started/example_scenes.html):

```
from manim import *

class OpeningManimExample(Scene):
    def construct(self):
        intro_words = Text("""
            The original motivation for manim was to
            better illustrate mathematical functions
            as transformations.
        """)
        intro_words.to_edge(UP)

        self.play(Write(intro_words))
        self.wait(2)

        # Linear transform
        grid = NumberPlane((-10, 10), (-5, 5))
        matrix = [[1, 1], [0, 1]]
        linear_transform_words = VGroup(
            Text("This is what the matrix"),
            IntegerMatrix(matrix, include_background_rectangle=True),
            Text("looks like")
        )
        linear_transform_words.arrange(RIGHT)
        linear_transform_words.to_edge(UP)
        linear_transform_words.set_stroke(BLACK, 10, background=True)

        self.play(
            ShowCreation(grid),
            FadeTransform(intro_words, linear_transform_words)
        )
        self.wait()
        self.play(grid.animate.apply_matrix(matrix), run_time=3)
        self.wait()

        # Complex map
        c_grid = ComplexPlane()
        moving_c_grid = c_grid.copy()
        moving_c_grid.prepare_for_nonlinear_transform()
        c_grid.set_stroke(BLUE_E, 1)
        c_grid.add_coordinate_labels(font_size=24)
        complex_map_words = TexText("""
            Or thinking of the plane as $\\mathds{C}$,\\\\
            this is the map $z \\rightarrow z^2$
        """)
        complex_map_words.to_corner(UR)
        complex_map_words.set_stroke(BLACK, 5, background=True)

        self.play(
            FadeOut(grid),
            Write(c_grid, run_time=3),
            FadeIn(moving_c_grid),
            FadeTransform(linear_transform_words, complex_map_words),
        )
        self.wait()
        self.play(
            moving_c_grid.animate.apply_complex_function(lambda z: z**2),
            run_time=6,
        )
        self.wait(2)
```

yields an error message:

```
    class OpeningManimExample(Scene):
                              ^^^^^
NameError: name 'Scene' is not defined. Did you mean: 'scene'?

[Done] exited with code=1 in 0.901 seconds
```

However, I have code for Manim with exactly the same structure, i.e. the `from manim import *` following by a `class NameOfTheClass(Scene):` that run perfectly well.

If I look up this error online I get posts that prompt to install Manim, discuss downloading the package versus pip installing, etc. However, is the error really about `Scene`? Because if this is the case it would happen in all Manim files with this structure, wouldn't it?

Trying from the terminal `from manimlib import *` also seems to be a problem, even though manimlib is installed:

```
PS C:\Users\j\Documents\MANIM> from manimlib import *
ParserError: 
Line |
   1 |  from manimlib import *
     |  ~~~~
     | The 'from' keyword is not supported in this version of the language.
```

---

Directory:

[image]

---

This is the output of

```
import manimlib; print(dir(manimlib))

[Running] python -u "c:\Users\anton\Documents\MANIM\test.py"
['__builtins__', '__cached__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__loader__', '__name__', '__package__', '__path__', '__spec__', 'animation', 'camera', 'config', 'constants', 'container', 'extract_scene', 'main', 'manimlib', 'mobject', 'scene', 'utils']

[Done] exited with code=0 in 8.02 seconds
```

Comment: Did you maybe create a file named `manim.py` in the same directory as the code you're running?

Comment: The example has `from manimlib import *`, but you are using `from manim import *`

Comment: @ThierryLathuille I'm not sure how to best answer, but I posted an Explorer snapshot in the OP. Hopefully that answers your question. Let me know, please.

Comment: You apparently didn't. Have you checked John Gordon's comment?

Comment: It has a concrete meaning, namely that there is no name "Scene" defined at the point your code tries to use it.

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you. I'm getting the same error with `from manimlib import *`.

Comment: @JohnGordon I wonder if the error message I just included in the OP when I try `from manimlib import *` directly from the terminal is the clue to the problem. Would you mind taking a look?

Comment: You tried to run `from manimlib import *` as though it were a powershell command.  Of course that will not work...

Comment: @JohnGordon It makes sense. Thank you. If I try to pip3 install manimlib it lets me know it's already there. Can you think given all this of a reason why the code would not run?

Comment: Show us the output of this small code sample `import manimlib; print(dir(manimlib))`

Comment: @JohnGordon Thank you very much for your interest in helping! Please find the output at the bottom of the OP.

Comment: Hmm.  Looking more closely at the manimlib [example](https://pypi.org/project/manimlib/), it is not executed using `python` at all, but instead a separate `manim` program.  And in the example you linked, it is executed using `manimgl`.  I think I'm beyond my knowledge here.